# Using Python3 with pybind11 from C++ with multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pybind11

I am trying to call a python class and use said class within a C++ program.  For this, I am trying to use pybind11.  My module establishes a multiprocessing.Process and then starts the process.  When ran from ipython or a script via: `python -m c2pymulti` the python code works as expected. However, when I run the code within c++ it seems to spawn or start the main process over and over again. Here is a simple example of my python code:

```
import os
import sys
from queue import Empty, Full
from multiprocessing import Queue as mQueue, Process as mProcess

class C2PyMulti(object):
    """docstring for TactileEngine"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.te_ops = MultiProcessTest()

    def compose(self,data): 
        self.te_ops.load_q(data)

class MultiProcessTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_q = mQueue()
        self.spawn_processes()

    def load_q(self, data):
        self.my_q.put(('print',data))

    def spawn_processes(self):
        args = (self.my_q,54)
        self.message_coordinator = mProcess(target=message_coordinator, args=args)
        try:
            # Starts the data processor
            val = self.message_coordinator.start()
            if val == 1:
                self.message_coordinator.join()
        except Exception:
            print('failed spawn!')


def message_coordinator(mQ,num):    
    print(num)
    while True:
        try:
            command, args= mQ.get(timeout=.0001)
            if  command == 'print':
                print(args)  
            elif command == 'end':
                return 1
        except (Empty):
            pass
```

Here is the example of the C++ code:

```
#define PATH_SEP '/'
#define GETCWD getcwd
#define CHDIR chdir
#endif
#include <iostream>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/eval.h>

#include <pybind11/embed.h>
#include <thread>         // std::this_thread::sleep_for
namespace py = pybind11;

bool ChangeDirectory(const char* dir) { return CHDIR(dir) == 0; }


void sleepcp(int milliseconds);

void sleepcp(int milliseconds) // Cross-platform sleep function
{
    clock_t time_end;
    time_end = clock() + milliseconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000;
    while (clock() < time_end)
    {
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::module c2py = py::module::import("c2pymulti");
    py::object c2pyMultClass = c2py.attr("C2PyMulti");
    py::object c2pyObj = c2pyMultClass();
    c2pyObj.attr("load_q")("hello");


    while (false) //if true it might crash computer due to mem issues.
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    std::cout << "after multi process queue!\n";

}
```

Here is the output I get when ran from ipython:

```
In [1]: import c2pymulti as c2p

In [2]: c = c2p.C2PyMulti()

In [3]: 54
In [3]: c.compose('hello')

hello
In [4]: c.compose('hello')

hello
```

and here is the output from running the c++ program:

```
Hello World!
after multi process queue!
Hello World!
after multi process queue!
Hello World!
after multi process queue!
Hello World!
after multi process queue!
Hello World!
after multi process queue!
Hello World!
after multi process queue!
Hello World!
after multi process queue!
Hello World!
after multi process queue!
Hello World!
after multi process queue!
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it never gets into the message_corrdinator method

Comment: It's the same basic problem in the duplicate; you need to handle all the things `multiprocessing` does to simulate forking manually (namely, it spawns a fresh process from `sys.executable` with arguments that tell it to change stuff such that it reimports the `__main__` module, but calls it `__mp_main__` so `if __name__ == '__main__':` guarded code isn't run. You have to manually respond to this "spawn launch" protocol yourself, because you've taken over for Python.

Comment: it is not an executable python file look above. It is not the same situation

Comment: It is the same. In both cases, there is a `pybind11`-based `main` (or `wmain`) that drives Python code that uses `multiprocessing`. The `pybind11` based `main` is being run over and over because it's the top-level executable, and it's not responding to being run again the way `python` itself would (instead running from scratch, which tries to launch the `multiprocessing` code again and again). The duplicate also worked fine when the Python code was run with Python itself, and failed when the Python code was run via the `pybind11`-based replacement executable.

Comment: my apologies; however, I can run the code and use exec. The issue is if I just  call ```py::exec(pyCode)``` with 
```cpy2 = C2PyMulti()
cpy2.compose('hello')
cpy2.compose('hello')
cpy2.compose('hello')
cpy2.compose('hello')
cpy2.compose('end')
del cpy2``` the same thing happends where the python code runs over and over again. 
```

Comment: It's the `multiprocessing` spawn implementation that does it; it's literally running your code again, from scratch, with special command line arguments. Change your `main` to accept the standard `int argc, char **argv`, and add a loop that prints out the contents of `argv`, you'll see that when you try to spawn a worker, you're invoked with `--multiprocessing-fork` and a few other arguments you don't expect. Because you don't change behavior in response to them, you blindly go ahead and load `multiprocessing` *again*, and launch a worker *again*.

Comment: You *might* be able to fix it by adding a line that calls `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` after all your imports and definitions, but before doing any of you "main-like" behaviors (e.g. launching `multiprocessing` workers).

Comment: we don't have a main.  It is being called from a DLL and we are using it as one would use it in ipython

Comment: Also we changed the process to a Thread from threading